# Passing functional component props to a static property in React

Tags: reactjs

Say, I have a functional React component:

```
const MyComponent = props => {...}
```

and I set a static property on it:

```
MyComponent.layout = MyLayoutComponent
```

Is there a way to pass/access the `props` from `MyComponent` to/in `MyLayoutComponent`?

Comment: No static methods will not have access to an instances props..... But why would you want to?

Comment: Well, in my specific case I'm using a dynamic route page component in Next.js, but the specific components at this route have a shared layout component which I set on _app.js. And because the route query parameters are available for `MyComponent`, I need to find a way to pass them to `MyLayoutComponent'.

Comment: If you need to pass data across to components in other parts of the app you would usually use a global state management like context API or redux. But you should be able to get your route data at any level using the useRouter hook. If you share some code to show what you are trying to do I can try give abetter answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can with something like this

```
const Bar = (props: any) => {
  console.log('bar props: ', props)
  // {foo: "FOO" ...}
  return <div>bar</div>
}

Bar.displayName = 'Bar'

const Foo = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(props.children, (child: any) => {
        console.log('name: ', child.type?.displayName)
        return React.cloneElement(child, props)
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

Foo.layout = Bar
```

...

```
  <Foo foo="FOO">
    <Foo.layout />
  </Foo>
```

[React children api](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)